# Iterate through a thread with loop and process multiple results

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to use threads to make my program run some parts in parallel and am struggling.

Goal is to process a list of links, `urlList` through the `ImageProcessor().processLink` function.  I have two problems I am trying to solve:

1. How do I loop this so it uses N number of threads in the pool, 10 in this case?  That is, I want to process 10 links at a time.
2. The processing function above returns a `File`, which I need to add to an array, `fileList`.  When it comes to multithreading, how will I handle this?

This is what i've got so far:

```
    ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr.split("\\r?\\n"))) ;
    ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    //process the requested files
    for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++){
        Future<File> value = executor.submit(new Callable<File>() {
            @Override
            public File call(int i) throws IOException {
                return new ImageProcessor().processLink(urlList.get(i));
            }
        });

        try {
            fileList.add(value.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the following:

```
    ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr.split("\\r?\\n"))) ;
    ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_SIZE);
    List<Future<File>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < urlList.size(); i++) {
        ImageProcessor proc = new ImageProcessor(urlList.get(i));
        final Future<File> future = executor.submit(proc);
        futures.add(future);
    }

    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < futures.size(); i++)
    {
        Future<File> result = futures.get(i);
        try {
            fileList.add(result.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    while (!executor.isTerminated()) { }
    System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Comment: The crucial point is to have two loops, first submit all jobs, then retrieve all results. The call to `awaitTermination` is unnecessary. Since there is no ongoing termination at this point, it will wait five seconds for no reason. Further, use  `List<String> urlList = Arrays.asList(arr.split("\\R"));`, no need to copy the `List` to an new `ArrayList` and `\R` is a simpler pattern for a line terminator. And the end of the program, after `shutdown`, calling `awaitTermination` would be the right thing instead of the `while (!executor.isTerminated()) { }` polling loop.

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback with explanations